# Azure Logic App Workflow Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-logic-apps

Having difficulty getting diagnostic details out of my logic app. I have enabled the diagnostics, bit the event hub and log analytics for work flow runtime. But at this time I'm not seeing anything coming out. I have also checked the diagnostic logs table and nothing. this is a very basic POC logic app.

Do I need to do anything else.

Comment: What diagnostics log table are you referring to? Have you tried turning on diagnostics to a storage account and checking the insights-logs-* blob containers? Are metrics for your logic app showing up in Azure Portal?

Comment: There is nothing in the diagnostics logs on the portal. The WorkfloRuntime is empty but I can see in the metrics tab if I filter by Actions that thigs happend. AM I misunderstanding what the diagnostic logs tab is for as it is not showing any errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the log analytics(OMS) workspace in azure and link it with the logic app. For the existing logic apps, we can add this via diagnostics settings under monitoring.